# Include Modal.vue in page1.vue and page2.vue

Tags: vue.js

I started using Laravel with **vue.js**, i have created some pages using **vue.js**
so i have **modal** that i would like to use in both of pages ( **page1.vue and page2.vue** ) without re write the modal html code again:

**Page1.vue**

```
<template>
   <div>Page 1 </div>
</template>
```

**Page2.vue**

```
<template>
   <div>Page 2 </div>
</template>
```

How can i share a modal.vue with this two pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just import the modal component into both pages. Here ive done it with a bool `modalBool` that will toggle weather the modal is displayed or not.

```
<template>
  <div>
    Page 1
    <modal v-if="modalBool"> </modal>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Modal from "./Modal.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    Modal,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      modalBool: false,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

You can add things like on close to reset the bool in the parent

```
<template>
  <div>
    Page 1
    <modal v-if="modalBool" v-on:close="showInvitationModal = false"> </modal>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here is an example of my modal that will emit `close` when closed. The parent is listening for this `close` and will reset the `modalBool`. This will be emitted if the user clicks outside of the modal or on the X

```
<template>
  <transition name="component-fade" mode="out-in">
    <div class="modal-background" @click.self="$emit('close')">
      <div class="modal-body shadow">
        <h2 class="modal-title">
          <div>{{ title }}</div>
          <div>
            <button class="btn-clear" @click="$emit('close');">
              <font-awesome-icon :icon="timesIcon" class="pointer" />
            </button>
          </div>
        </h2>

        <div>
          <slot></slot>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>
```